# Is there a way to display table name as a result of the SELECT clause depending on the table used in the FROM clause(Oracle)?

Tags: oracle

I need some in-built keyword/function which would display the table name of the query as a result of the SELECT clause of the query.

For Example:

Table Products on Database TestDB, contains the following data

ID   ProductName
1    Toys
2    Flowers

```
select ora_database_name,ProductName from Products;
```

The above query will return the following output,

TestDB  Toys
TestDB  Flowers

So is there a similar keyword or function for displaying table name?

```
Select <keyword/function>, ProductName from Products;
```

Expected output:

Products Toys
Products Flowers

Currently I am using something like this to mitigate the aforementioned issue,

```
Select 'Products' as TableName, ProductName from Products;
```

P.S.:
Sorry if the question is convoluted/Confusing!

Comment: If you write the SQL query, you know the name of the table. What is wrong with hard-coding it in the query as you have done? By the way, what do you want to display for a query that joins two tables?

Comment: The problem is, I combine the results of multiple queries using 'union' and I often change the table names used in the queries using find and replace feature in the GUI tool, for e.g. SQL Developer, which also changes the hardcoded names as well which is only helpful some times.

Comment: Perhaps there is a different solution to your problem than the one you propose. Why not describe your real problem and ask for suggested solutions rather than asking for a way to implement your proposed solution?

Answer (score 1):

**The following is not for production use!**
I'm doing this just for fun, to show what can we do in oracle:

```sql
select
   (select sql_text from v$sqlarea q,v$session s where s.sid=userenv('sid') and s.sql_id=q.sql_id) stext
  ,regexp_replace(
     (select sql_text from v$sqlarea q,v$session s where s.sid=userenv('sid') and s.sql_id=q.sql_id)
    ,'.*?from ((\s*,?\s*\w+)+)\s*(where|$)'
    ,'[\1]'
    ,1,1,'i'
  ) from_clause
from dual, dual;
```

Results:

```
STEXT                                                                            FROM_CLAUSE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------
select    (select sql_text from v$sqlarea q,v$session s where s.sid=userenv('sid [dual, dual]
') and s.sql_id=q.sql_id) stext   ,regexp_replace(      (select sql_text from v$
sqlarea q,v$session s where s.sid=userenv('sid') and s.sql_id=q.sql_id)     ,'.*
?from ((\s*,?\s*\w+)+)\s*(where|$)'     ,'[\1]'     ,1,1,'i'   ) from_clause fro
m dual, dual
```

Or from v$sql_plan:

```sql
select
  (  select
          listagg(obj, ',') within group(order by obj)
     from (
        select distinct object_type||':'/*||object_owner||'.'*/||object_name as obj
        from v$session s, v$sql_plan p 
        where s.sid    = userenv('sid')
          and s.sql_id = p.sql_id 
          and s.sql_child_number = p.child_number
          and p.object_name is not null
          and p.object_name not like '%$%'
     )
  ) objects
from t1,t2,t3,t4
where rownum=1;
```

Results:

```sql
OBJECTS
------------------------------------------------------------
INDEX (UNIQUE):PK_T2,INDEX (UNIQUE):PK_T4,TABLE:T1,TABLE:T3
```

With some preprocessing (replacing indexes with their table names):

```sql
select
  (  select
          listagg(obj, ',') within group(order by obj)
     from (
        select distinct 
           case 
              when object_type like 'INDEX%'
                 then 
                   (select min(table_name) from all_indexes i where i.index_name=p.object_name and i.owner=p.object_owner)
              else object_name 
           end as obj
        from v$session s, v$sql_plan p 
        where s.sid    = userenv('sid')
          and s.sql_id = p.sql_id 
          and s.sql_child_number = p.child_number
          and p.object_name is not null
          and p.object_name not like '%$%'
          and p.object_owner!='SYS'
     )
  ) objects
from t1,t2,t3,t4
where rownum=1;
```

Results:

```sql
OBJECTS
------------
T1,T2,T3,T4
```